# error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'bitstream::bitset_extractor<T> VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am facing strange problem.Same code is working fine in vs 2008 and VS 2010 **Debug and Dubug Unicode** Version but failed to compile in **Release and Release Unicode**.
What could be the reason for this.

This code is generating the error

```
struct bitset_extractor
{
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag   iterator_category;
    typedef T                           value_type;
    typedef T*                          pointer;
    typedef T&                          reference;
    typedef ptrdiff_t                   difference_type;

    bitset_extractor(const boost::dynamic_bitset<T>& bs, T *buffer)
        : bs_(bs), buffer_(buffer), current_(0)
    {}

    bitset_extractor(const bitset_extractor& it)
        : bs_(it.bs_), buffer_(it.buffer_), current_(it.current_)
    {}

    T& operator*()
    {
        return buffer_[current_];
    }

    bitset_extractor& operator++()
    {
        ++current_;
        return *this;
    }
   private:
    void operator=(T const&);           // unimplemented

    const boost::dynamic_bitset<T>&     bs_;
    T * const                           buffer_;
    unsigned int                        current_;
};

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(275): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>           C:\vikram\Project\Seurat\src\app\logitech\LogiRTP\Library\Filters\plc\common\bitstream.h(195): could be 'void bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>::operator =(const T &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>, bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(2176) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Iter &std::_Rechecked<_OutIt,_OutIt>(_Iter &,_UIter)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>,
1>              _OutIt=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>,
1>              _UIter=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>
1>          ]
1>          C:\vikram\Project\Seurat\3rdparty\boost\boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp(1090) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,BlockOutputIterator>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>,
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<unsigned char,std::allocator<uint8_t>>,
1>              BlockOutputIterator=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>,
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<unsigned char,std::allocator<uint8_t>>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\vikram\Project\Seurat\src\app\logitech\LogiRTP\Library\Filters\plc\common\bitstream.h(210) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::to_block_range<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>,bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>>(const boost::dynamic_bitset<Block> &,BlockOutputIterator)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t,
1>              T=uint8_t,
1>              Block=uint8_t,
1>              BlockOutputIterator=bitstream::bitset_extractor<uint8_t>
1>          ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(275): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'bitstream::bitset_extractor<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=uint8_t
1>          ]
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code which generates this error? Kind of impossible to debug without it.

Comment: `void bitset_extractor::operator=(T const&)` is `private`

Comment: @TravisGockel But is compiling fine in Debug and Debug Unicode version

Comment: I'm not sure since you didn't post the line which is producing the error but I think it has something to do with your assignment operator

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I have posted the compiler output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `bitset_extractor` is being used as an iterator, but it doesn't meet all of the requirements for an iterator.

The `std::copy` function is calling `operator=` with two `bitset_extractor<uint8_t>` objects as it attempts to convert the original iterator into a checked iterator. Since no checked iterator exists for user defined iterators, the checked iterator type and original iterator type are the same, resulting in a regular copy of the iterator being used.

The culprit is the `_Rechecked` function, which is used to convert a regular iterator into a checked iterator. This is done differently, depending on the iterator debug level; that's why your Debug build works, but not your Release build, as they have different iterator debug levels by default.

The solution is to implement `operator=` for `bitset_extractor`. If you want to use it as an iterator, it **must** support all of the functionality required for an iterator of it's type.

Disabling checked iterators won't help. Your iterators will still go through the `_Rechecked` function, no matter what you do.

Comment: What if he changed it to be an input iterator?

Comment: Changing it to any type of iterator will do. At the moment, it's being used as an iterator, but it doesn't meet the requirements of any iterator, because it doesn't provide copy assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved .I added  _SECURE_SCL=1 in VS Project Setting->preprocessor.

It is working fine.